# Регулярное выражение php - нужна помощь в составлении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!

Помогите, пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение для следующей задачи: Есть текст в переменной $text, в нем попадаются такие куски [url="https://site/path/2017/07/28/img.jpg"] (их может быть много разных), мне нужно найти все такие куски, вытащить все что между кавычками в url записать в массив, а оригинал из текста удалить. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XCcjbZ/2/ - пример регулярного выражения

Comment: `[url="([^"]+)"]`. Немного поправил ответ PotroNik.

Comment: Спасибо друзья!

Comment: а если такая кнструкция? подскажите пожалуйста: [url="site/imagehosting/2017/07/28/9340058316.jpg"]
[img]
site/imagehosting/2017/07/28/thumb_9340058316.jpg
[/img]
[/url]

Comment: @Node_pro нежадное `.*?`нагляднее вроде ж гораздо чем `[^"]+`

Comment: @DexCol, а что именно из этого требуется достать?

Comment: @PotroNik два выражения: 1ое, достать урл который в url="", а второе, выбрать все чтобы удалить. Спасибо вам за участие. Я очень благодарен вашим откликам!

Comment: @DexColt посмотрите пример https://regex101.com/r/XCcjbZ/3, выражение должно подходить и под первый и под второй случай

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю на последний ваш комментарий:

```
$arr = array();

$text = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\[url="([^"]+)"\](?: *\[img\][^[]+\[\/img\] *\[\/url\])?/',
    function ($matches) use (&$arr) {
        $arr[] = $matches[1];
        return '';
    },
    $text
);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Я неописуемо благодарен вашему отклику! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: извиняюсь за то, что вмешиваюсь, но 'Если ответ решил вашу проблему или помог вам в поиске решения больше других, отметьте его принятым'. Спасибо.